# How do I open a webpage with BeautifulSoup and output a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How do I use BeautifulSoup to find all letters from yahoo.com containing the letter M and output it to a txt. file?

I have tried the script below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://www.yahoo.com"     
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: "all letters ... containing the letter M" ??

Comment: letters, as in, something that you send through mail?

Comment: Please be clear with the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather vague question so I am going to make a couple assumptions in order to answer it. Specifically, I am assuming that by "find all letters from yahoo.com containing the letter M" you mean find all *words* containing the letter 'M'.

To do this you need to parse the html in content by calling

```
BeautifulSoup(content)
```

more information [on the beautiful soup website](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup).

This returns an object that you can call methods on for extracting certain text. For example

```
find_all('p')
```

will extract all the text within `<p>` tags and return a list containing all of the paragraphs on the page. This is useful because most of the content on yahoo.com will be within `<p>` tags. Now that you have isolated the text you are interested in you are ready to search for words containing the letter M. Moving right along...

For this I would use the regular expression

```
\b[A-z]*[mM][A-z]*\b
```

which matches words containing M or m. You can change `[mM]` to `M` if you want to exclude the lower case. If you are new to regular expressions you can tweak this one in [gskinner](http://regexr.com?36iht). It's pretty cool because it breaks the expression down with explanations if you mouse over it.

Putting it all together:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
#extract paragraphs
paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
words = []
#iterate through paragraphs and split into individual words
for x in paragraphs:
   words = words + x.getText().split()
#match words with 'm' or 'M'
regex = re.compile(r'\b[A-z]*[mM][A-z]*\b')
words_with_m = filter(lambda i: regex.search(i), words)
```

gave me this when I ran it

> made small much more More million most AM admits Abrams claims many
>   him More Entertainment measuring income employment environment More
>   Most home man claimed 'embassy' woman home time removed… More 'Climate
>   man family from home More From Money Minute may many Primetime Time
>   Money Minute may many Primetime Time

as you can see you need a little more work to filter out symbols. This is not too hard just use another regex.

```
filtered = [re.sub(r'\W','',x) for x in words_with_m]
```

this will remove all special characters. And returns

> made small much more mansion small much AM admits Abrams claims many
>   him More Entertainment measuring income employment environment More
>   Most Margaret prominent women time anthem More Climate man family from
>   home More From Money Minute may many Primetime Time Money Minute may
>   many Primetime Time

To open a file as writable and write to it

```
with open('path_to_file/file', 'w') as f:
   for x in filtered:
      f.writelines(x + ' ')
```

will write the words containing m separated by white space.

Hope this helps! In the future I would do a bit more research before asking an open ended question like this. We are happy to help out, and if you are clear about what you want it will help us help you. Happy coding!